# What do you call this kind of editing where you put color-filled layers on top?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, illustration, style-identification

I'm really interested in doing this kind of thing but I don't know what words to search:

[image]

This is what someone did to a Clockwork Angel book cover. So the person who did this basically put layers on top of a picture. I read her tutorial on how she did this but I want to know more. She only called this "graphic edit" which really doesn't help much. She is also inactive in tumblr so asking her would probably useless.

I'm not really familiar with the technical terms of ps so I don't know how to look for this kind of thing. I'm also sorry if the question wasn't worded right. Thanks in advance!

The tutorial she made: https://tmblr.co/ZpRNtt11Ehisy

Answer (score 1):

Search for Photoshop layer blend modes. This image seems to have several layers with shapes and letters, their blend modes might have been changed as well as their layer opacity.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for gravedigging, but this is more related to vector watercolor styles.

You can create this watercolor style effect in Illustrator using different transparencies of color. **[Here is a great tutorial](http://designinstruct.com/drawing-illustration/make-watercolor-and-marker-style-portraits-with-illustrator/)** to get you started. this tutorial has a lot of depth, but it would be rather simple to bring it back to be a little more minimalistic.

Hope this helps!